Quitting and reloading another function
I want to write a one-line command which will quit the current session (with all the loaded packages etc) and reload another package. But when I try
Reload := (Quit[];
  Get["/home/tanmoy/prj_23/nb_packages/myRICS/LoadFile"])

as expected, it closes the session and does not load the LoadFile. I need an idea to execute this.

I think Quit[] has to be on its own cell or command. Next command should be on separate cell.
